# javascript variable to php NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use simple AJAX request to pass JavaScript variable to PHP via AJAX.

This my AJAX request:

```
var image_url = "example";
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  //url: 'index.php', // the same file
  data: { image_url : image_url },
  success: function(data) {
      alert here works! 
  }
```

In the same file, on the first line i have

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['image_url']); ?>
```

On my page I see always NULL

Can someone help me?

Comment: `var_dump` logs the content of that PHP variable onto the document you're writing to. You're never creating the `image_url` variable in the JS world, so JS cannot send it in your AJAX call. There's probably some more code that this, or you should get a JS Error because `image_url` is never declared here.

Comment: i do not think it matters. but ajax request is generated in modal window.

Comment: Really sorry for not including this line, image_url variable is obviously defined above ajax request. My fault!

Comment: Are you saying you are seeing 'NULL' printed on your page when you load it in your browser?  The same page that you are later doing a POST request to, but on page load would not be a POST and that variable would not exist so it would print NULL on page load?

Comment: Look at the doc for $_POST: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php , it picks up variables that have been posted with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data`. But you're posting it as a JSON data because jQuery will guess the datatype from your data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. If you want to use $_POST, you need to send the data urlencoded, not as JSON.

Comment: @Greg no, if you don't tell jQuery to make it json it will convert it to a param string automatically.  `{ blah: blah }` isn't json.  It's json in the source file but after it is compiled and ran it will be an object at that point.  `var x = '{"key":"value"}';` would be a variable containing json.

Comment: Ajax debugging should be done in the browser network activity monitor. How did you check `image_url` ?

Comment: @Taplar you're correct, they do send it as urlencoded here. The 'Intelligent Guess' mentioned by the docs is clear enough on what it'll do when, IMHO. I assumed the opposite: that a string would be sent as urlencoded, and an object as JSON (which could be achieved too).

Comment: I'm assuming the issue isn't with the ajax request.  I'm assuming the issue is that the user is hitting the same page for page load and for the ajax request.  And if the page load is not a post or does not have that variable passed to it, then if var_dump returns the result to the page the user would see the NULL on the page load request.  Which would mean the user needs to either ignore that logic for the page load, or split out that specific logic to another endpoint so it doesn't get ran for the page load, and only runs for the ajax request.

Comment: thanks for the answers. User snapjs has right about my fault, now i changed code, to simple post request generated in javascipt. it works!

Answer (score 0):

Note that all the server-side PHP code on has already run once you're interacting with the page client-side, so you won't be able to access the `$_POST['image_url']` using PHP as you appear to be attempting.

That being said, any resultant data from your AJAX request will be in the data variable of your `success` function.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  //url: 'index.php', // the same file
  data: { image_url : image_url },
  success: function(data)
  {
      console.log(data); // this is where your data is
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, i think i understand. Is there any option to pass my js variable to php code in one file?

Comment: Well, you can just do a regular (non-AJAX) post, and reload your page.  Otherwise, no, you can't rerun server-side code because you're now in the client's browser.

Comment: ok, let's try this. Thank you for fast answers. Great support for begginners here. I am really grateful to you